# Jenkin's schedule not triggering build

Tags: jenkins, schedule

I have the follow schedule defined within Jenkins for a particular project:

```
H 8,10,13 * * 1-5
```

My expectation for this schedule was to trigger a build around 8 am, 10 pm, and 1pm, every work day.

But the build never fires during the times scheduled. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Are there other settings I need to apply to the project to automatically trigger this build for the given schedule?

If I just force the project to build, it succeeds.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. This is not a source controlled build. It actually fires a script to deploy one of our other builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schedule you specified above uses the special "H" value for minutes, which randomizes the minutes value based on the job name.  You job will run at some time between 8am-8:59am, 10am-10:59am and 1pm-1:59pm every weekday (assuming that your Jenkins server is on the same time zone as you are).

The minutes value will remain the same as long as you don't change the name of the job.

Comment: That is what I expected, but it does not work. 1'oclock came and went, and the build never started.

Comment: Actually, taking the `H` into account, the schedule would run the job sometime between 8-8:59am, between 10-10:59am and between 1-1:59pm.